# Alarm doesn't trigger after reboot

Tags: android, alarmmanager, reboot

I have an alarm to reset a data connection say every 15 minutes. The problem is, once the phone is rebooted, the application gets killed and the alarm (service) doesn't trigger anymore.
(This is not a duplicate, the other similar questions on SO do not solve my problem.)

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
 <receiver
        android:name="com.sang.mobiledata.ResetBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.sang.mobiledata.IntentAction.RECEIVE_RESETCONN_UPDATE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>
```

Broadcast Receiver:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // if(CONN_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
    if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(
            "com.sang.mobiledata.IntentAction.RECEIVE_RESETCONN_UPDATE")) {
        MainActivity objMain = new MainActivity();

        objNetwork.setMobileDataEnabled(context, false);
        objNetwork.setMobileDataEnabled(context, true);

    }

    if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(
            "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {

            // code to restart/resume/retain alarm
```

Code to fire alarm (on the onClick):

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(
                    "com.sang.mobiledata.IntentAction.RECEIVE_RESETCONN_UPDATE");
            myIntent.putExtra("FLAG_KEY", false);
            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, myIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this
                    .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

            calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
            long interval = intHrs * 3600000 + intMins * 60000;
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    calendar.getTimeInMillis(), interval, pi);
            long mins = interval / 60000;
            Toast.makeText(
                    MainActivity.this,
                    "Data Connection will be reset every " + mins
                            + " minute(s).", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Did you try setting export to true for your receiver in your manifest ?

Comment: No, what does that do?

Comment: As your receiver is gonna be called by another process / app (the android system), you need to specify that this receiver can be used from outside your app.

Comment: I also really suggest you look at this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/a/15723813/693752

Comment: Is your BootReceiver being called upon phone reboot? Maybe it's not the problem here but I think you should put one action per `<intent-filter>` in your manifest.

Answer (score 4):

Read the `AlarmManager` document, there it is written, that `AlarmManager` will not hold alarms after reboot.

As per the **`Android` Developers**,

> [...](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). Registered alarms are retained while the device is asleep (and can optionally wake the device up if they go off during that time), but will be **cleared if it is turned off and rebooted.**

And regarding `BOOT_COMPLETED`, they write:

> [...](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) This is broadcast once, after the system has finished booting. It can be used to perform application-specific initialization, such as installing alarms. You must hold the RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED permission in order to receive this broadcast.

As for permission is concerned, you have already registered that. Well what probably happening is, the service **`BOOT_COMPLETED`** is being used locally, with the application. The `reboot` of the mobile is **system activity**, which is not *overridden* to accomplish re-registry of the alarms being saved. But I am not sure. So, you need to do something when execution comes in hand of `BOOT_COMPLETED`.

### Read [Automatically starting Services in Android after booting](http://blog.vogella.com/2011/12/11/automatically-starting-services-in-android-after-booting/), this might help you with it.

What I did was, I registered all the alarms and formed a `database`, using `SQLite`; On `restart`, I use to reset all the alarms. Well that worked for me. If you want to go with my process then,

Make a database for your alarms, and save them there. Write your application in such a way that, when the phone restarts, the `AlarmManager` resets all the alarms. This is how it works.

---

In [Automatically starting Services in Android After booting](http://blog.vogella.com/2011/12/11/automatically-starting-services-in-android-after-booting/) again. It is written:

> Also note that as of Android 3.0 the user needs to have started the application at least once before your application can receive android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED events.

Comment: Read the guy's code.  He's registering for BOOT_COMPLETED notifications, but either not receiving them or not correctly resetting his alarm when he does.  But whatever the issue is he's certainly already trying to do what you say.

Comment: @ Veer: Whichever way I do it, it should catch the BOOT_COMPLETED action in the onReceive (rt?) which is not happening.

Comment: @Adi.. And read [this](http://blog.vogella.com/2011/12/11/automatically-starting-services-in-android-after-booting#div-comment-13200). read other comments, they are useful. And please let us know what is the right way to do that. Where have you made mistake or anything.

Comment: I read all that. I am trying it the DB way. Although thats causing problems as well. I really dont know how to save the alarms to the database.

Comment: @Veer Do you have the code for the DB way so that I can have a look?

Comment: @Adi: Ya... I know.... you have to fight for DB in Android, actually it will cause a problem with the `Context` part. Well regarding that, you need to save the time with `CALENDAR.getTimeInMillis()` in the database. Now I think, you got my point. Go through my questions on android (in my profile), you will find many questions there with that.

Comment: @Adi: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578098/save-alarm-in-android): this was my question that I asked days back.